# Can I buy less than 20GB of additional storage on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Could  you please add smaller packages (1-2gb for example) for a cheaper price? The 20gb is too much for me and I see no point paying for something I propably won't use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu One does offer 2 GB free. Why pay when you can get it for free :D. But again I donot know if it is a limited time offer.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a limited offer and you can get 2GB for free. Me and my daughters have 2GB for free each. We share data even when I'm away. It's just awesome :)

and 2GB is enough yeah.